# Where is Help Indexer.app on OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Where is Help Indexer.app on OSX Mountain Lion, I need this to create a Help Book. I have Xcode installed but cannot find it anywhere, the Online Help says it should be in /Developer/Utilities but I do not have a Developer folder and canot find a Developer application to install.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Xcode 4's application menu under the "Open Developer Tool" submenu, select "More Developer Tools...".  This goes to a web site where you can download various packages.

The package you want is named "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012".

The `/Developer` path is obsolete, it's wrong documentation now.  Once Xcode installs this tool it will be located somewhere under Xcode's bundle (`/Applications/Xcode.app/...`) and it will be launchable from the Xcode application menu.

Answer (score 2):

Currently in Xcode 7.3.1, the More Developer Tools link is broken. For those who cannot find Help Indeexer, go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and search for "Auxiliary Tools for Xcode 7". After opening the .dmg file, you can copy Help Indexer app into your directory.

Comment: Now in 2018 this link works, but needed package called "Additional Tools for Xcode 9".